# Audio modification or synthesis in phonegap

Tags: audio, mobile, cordova

Is it posible to do something else with audio in phonegap than playing or recording it?

I'm developing an app that needs to be able to change sound's pitch, modify it with effects or at least synthesize it. I like how fast is to develop simple applications for multiple mobile plataforms with Phonegap, it'll be really useful to know if some kind of audio manipulation can be done with it in any way.

Thank you.

Comment: u can always write plugins for it :)

Comment: Thank you, I know, and I might do it for the comunity. Although the benefits of using Phonegap for multiplataform development of an audio app aren't that big when I have to write a plug In for each OS.

Comment: Hey Oscar, did you manage to find a solution for this? Thanks.

Comment: Hiya, not really. I didn't have the time to develop plug-ins, so I got into videogame sdk's that developed for multiple mobile plataforms. Now, I'll tell you that we won't need to worry about that for long; Google's sound api got into the W3C recomendation and now it's going to be in the new versions of safari mobile and chrome for android. It doesn't renders audio in javascript, so it is really fast. Relatively new phones should be able to enjoy it.

Comment: Hey Oscar, I'm interested in the same topic. Html5 audio api looks very promising. I'll update you later today.